# Django Simple Captcha - Error in {{ form.as_p }} - 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'

Tags: python, django, captcha, simplecaptcha

I'm using Django 1.6 with mongoengine.

I just started to try the simple captcha but I have the following error.

As it is said in http://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html

I installed in my env, added to Installed apps, I didn't run syncdb because I work with MongoDB and this is not necessary and finally I added the url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')), into my url app file.

My form.py looks like :

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class PostForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
    captcha = CaptchaField()
```

And my view:

```
def post_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PostForm()
    else:
        # A POST request: Handle Form Upload
        form = PostForm(request.POST) # Bind data from request.POST into a PostForm

        # If data is valid, proceeds to create a new post and redirect the user
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.cleaned_data['user']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            connect('reborn')
            User.create_user(user,password,email)
            #return HttpResponse("Usuari nou creat")
            return render(request, 'game/welcomeuser.html', {
                'user': user,
            })
    return render(request, 'game/post_form_upload.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

So when the form is rendered it gaves me this error :

```
AttributeError at /game/form_upload.html
'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'

In template /.../post_form_upload.html, error at line 2
'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'
1   <form action='/game/form_upload.html' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
2   {{ form.as_p }} <- HERE
3   <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
4   </form>
5
```

What's wrong with form.as_p ?
Without this captcha runned fine.

Comment: Have you ran `./manage.py migrate` or `./manage.py syncdb`?

Comment: I didn't, It's explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run syncdb or migrate or create table `captcha_captchastore` in some other way, since it is required for simple captcha.

**Edit**:
I am probably wrong about creating the schema, since you are right about it is not being required.

But here is an idea. Mongoddb engine uses [djangotoolbox](https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox) which has class `djangotoolbox.db.base.NonrelDatabaseWrapper` didn't have that attribute `Database` until this [commit (line marked)](https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox/commit/57a0d7cd189fa93454617bcd28dd3e6b57466e6d#diff-9f8b0675c15c1a3d856737938091cbb0R693) So make sure you got the right version.

Let me know if I am wrong and what the actual solution was.

Comment: Thanks, do u know where I can find the structure of this table ? thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't have much experience with mongoDB, is that what you're looking for: https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/blob/master/captcha/models.py#L36

Comment: I think I got it. Do this:
   from djangotoolbox.db.base import NonrelDatabaseWrapper
   hasattr(NonrelDatabaseWrapper, 'Database')

if you got False you got an old version of djangotoolbox
here is the commit that fixed it: https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox/commit/57a0d7cd189fa93454617bcd28dd3e6b57466e6d